# Firefox loading page twice (or 3 times), shows as Abort 200 in firebug

Tags: http, firefox, abort

I am experiencing a strange situation where Firefox is loading a page 2 or 3 times just to show it once. I have looked into obvious things like empty image tags and such, but can't figure it out.

Using firebug, I can see in quick succession, the browser is getting a 200 Aborted and then the 200 OK, before loading the other elements of the page. Looking at my server logs, I only see the 200 OKs, nothing that is like an abort. Does anyone know why this happens? It happens with simple link clicks, no ajax in play when this occurs. This is causing extra server load, and also double activity for operations that are not idempotent.

Comment: could you share the screenshot of Firebug?

Comment: indeed any javascript, jquery, html would be nice, the firebug logs would be nice as well.

Comment: I'll upload some stuff when I get back to this soon! Thank you - this has been stagnant for awhile and I haven't revisited it.

Answer (score 2):

**Firebug causes a second HTTP GET request of @fontface font-files**

http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=4649

I had the same issue but that whose Firebuq buq :)

Comment: Not getting any fonts in this case

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I have seen close to this is bad .htaccess redirects. If you are using a linux server, check all of the .htaccess files in the folder that the file is in, the folders that you are linking to and also all the parent folders.

Answer (score 1):

200 Abort is sent when you call the [abort() method on XMLHTTPRequest objects](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-abort-method). Maybe you should post some related JS code or look for cases where abort() is being called.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to look into this. I'm using a bunch of libraries - maybe one of them is doing this.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is completely related to firebug. Try using Firefox's in-built Web Console with "Net" option enabled.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was a network issue blocking the https: transfers (SSL session not trusted). Once the credentials were accepted, the transfers changed from ABORTED to Success.

Answer (score -1):

Check that there arent empty src properties in img tags.

Comment: I mentioned in my original post that I have already checked that. It is the first request  that firebug says is getting aborted, there aren't two  successful requests.